# Show if $\phi$ is a ring isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$, then $\phi$ is the identity mapping.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show if $\phi$ is a RING isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$, then $\phi$ is the identity mapping.

I don't really know where to start with this one. I know that since $\phi$ is an isomorphism, it is a homomorphism that is both one-to-one and onto.  Since it is a homomorphism, $\phi$ satisfies the following.

(i) $\phi(0)=0$

(ii) $\phi(-a)=-\phi(a)$ $\forall a\in\mathbb{Z}$

(iii) $\phi(\mathbb{Z})$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$.

But I don't see how to relate these properties to the conclusion that $\phi$ is the identity mapping.

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated. ^_^

Comment: Note that once you know $\phi(1)$, you also know $\phi(2)=\phi(1+1)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)$, etc.

Comment: @SteveD gave you the answer, but you can in fact show (using the same strategy, and a bit of induction) that for any commutative ring $R$ with $1$, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow R$ which is completely determined by these three properties. Note that this in fact is a more general version of your result, as the identity is certainly a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, and then we apply uniqueness.

Comment: The problem doesn't state that $\phi$ is a commutative ring isomorphism.  Is there a way to show it is?

Comment: Well yes $\phi(ab)$ = $\phi(ba)$ isn't it? as ab = ba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\phi(1)=\phi(1 \cdot 1) =\phi(1) \phi(1)$$

Also $\phi(1) \neq 0$ (WHY?)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\phi(1)$. Then for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\phi(a)=\phi(a\cdot 1)=\phi(a)\phi(1)\Rightarrow \phi(1)=1$ . Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a domain this cancellation is allowed. Therefore $\phi(n)=n$.