# Let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a ring isomorphism. Show that $\phi$ is the identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a ring isomorphism. Show that $\phi$ is the identity.

I know that there exist a similar question ([Show if $\phi$ is a ring isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$, then $\phi$ is the identity mapping.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522053/show-if-phi-is-a-ring-isomorphism-of-mathbbz-to-mathbbz-then-phi-i)), but I think my question is a little bit different.

Is it possible to show this problem with the fact : A function is affine if and only if it is convex et concave?

Comment: I have already solve the problem, but I would like to know other possibilities

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. I've deleted my answer, which did not actually address your  question; I would suggest editing to make it clearer. (I also suggest changing the title.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that $x\ge0$ if and only if there exists $y$ with $x=y^2$. It follows that $\phi(x)\ge0$ if and only if $x\ge0$; now it follows that $\phi$ is non-decreasing, and then since $\phi$ is a bijection it must be continuous. It's easy to see that $\phi(r)=r$ for every rational $r$, and so $\phi(x)=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: Could you complete the proof? Some steps are ambigious for me.

Comment: You say you've already solved the problem... What steps above are the ones that bother you? (And how does the solution you found go? What I wrote seems like the straightforward argument - it's the same as what Noah Schweber said...)

Comment: Morally the same, in fact once we see the big trick his treatment of the details was simpler...

Comment: Is it possible you can show the first statement of your proof. BTW, you say that one bijective function is continuous. Is he missing a hypothesis that is true, for example, homomorphism, strictly monotone.

Comment: You want me to explain why $x\ge0$ if and only if there exists $y$ with $x=y^2$? I'm not sure I follow your next comment... If $f:\Bbb R \to\Bbb R$ is increasing then at each point the left and right limits exist. If the two-sided limits are equal at every point then $f$ is continuous, while if there exists a point where the right limit is strictly larger than the left limit then $f(\Bbb R)\ne \Bbb R)$. Not sure if that answers your questions, not being sure what the questions are...

Comment: Let me fill in the details. Suppose $f(x)\neq x$ for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$, say $f(x)<x$. Let $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x)<r<x$. $f(x)\geq f(r)=r$ since $f$ in nondecreasing, contradiction.